# Unable to make the confirm delete work in Angular

Tags: angular

Trying to activate the delete button when having a confirmation box popping out and when clicking delete it should delete the line

My delete function is as per below and I copied it in my popupcomponent ts file:

```
deleteBilling(id: string) {
   this.billingservice.deleteBilling(id).subscribe(
  resp => {
    console.log(resp);
    this.displayBilling()
  },
  err => console.error(err));
  


 }
```

I have copied the same in the popupcomponent html file on the actual button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="deleteBilling(billing.id)">Confirm Deletion</button>
```

Why does it not work ? If I remove popup confirmation my delete function works

I am adding an attempt to link popup to the delete function:

```
popupTest(id: string) {
this.popupService.dialogOpen('Are you sure you want to delete?')
  .afterClosed().subscribe(resp => {
    //console.log(resp)
    if (resp) {
     //this.popupComponent.deleteBilling(id)??
//this.deletebilling(id)??
    

    }
  });
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a stackblitz? Do you see any errors anywhere?

Comment: Define _does not work_. Did you try debugging?

Comment: where and when is calling `popupTest` function? and plese share popup component.ts file

Comment: PopupTest is called when clicking the Delete button which shows at this moment the popup box and calls a service ts file to close (if the X or cancel button is clicked). The second part of popupTest is what I am not sure what to put when the Parent has the delete function and how to call that function. I tried to add the delete function in the popupcomponent ts file (as in effect it comes from my API definition for delete function) too but does not work.

Comment: I think I know what is the problem. let me create simple example for you

Comment: You are using material dialog, right?

Comment: yes with that MAT_DIALOG_DATA thing that does not want to work - keeps showing error. I am trying to make if True then do an action (true being I confirmed deletion)

Comment: I used in popupcomponent.ts file this constructor: constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any)
It has other constructors but this is the one I believe that passes the value True? or I am missing something ... and MAT_DIALOG_DATA Is ok now

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xcd91i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts here is the example

Comment: Thank you Ashot - this worked !!! appreciate it!!!

Comment: no problem, please answer your own question, with the explanation, how you fixed it, to help others, Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say "copied the deleteBilling function in your popupcomponent ts"?

If you are using a component for the popup and the delete logic is in the parent, you will need to emit an event:

Add this to your popup.component.ts:

```js
@Output() deleteEvent

deleteBilling(billing.id): void {
  deleteEvent.emit(billing.id)
}
```

In Parent template:

```html
<app-popup (deleteEvent)="deleteBilling($event)"></app-popup>
```

However, I would consider using a 'modal' or dialog component (an actual popup). These are usually defined within the (parent) component, and thus don't require you to emit an event to the parent. (Both angular bootstrap and angular material are good options.)

They have all the functionality built in and you should be able to find a lot of examples on them.

Comment: Let me know if this answer fits your problem, I will  take another look if needed. Like @Nicholas_K said, we can more easily help you when you create a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/). Cheers

Comment: Thanks. Not familiar with StackBlitz at this stage sorry. I do have an actual popup appearing - to cancel/close it works, but to delete it does not work. I added a popup function: The delete function is in the parent and I click the button from the parent then a popup appears but the delete function does not work. I have added the testPopup in my source message if it helps? it is called popupTest

Comment: Stackblitz is rather easy to use. Just create an account, start an angular project by clicking the angular icon, and add any dependencies you need using the textbox at the bottom left of the screen. When you are done, just save, and share the project.